# Best practice for modifying collection attributes functionally

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

I'm curious how to go about implementing a class that obeys strict functional programming rules.

For example, if I have a class that has two attributes and I have a method that modifies them, how would I go about doing so? The attributes would be private vals, and the method would have to return a new instance of the attribute every time it modifies it. This is fine, except I would like to keep it contained, meaning I would need a way to set the val.

What would be the best way to do this so that I don't have thousands of instances of say, a collection, floating around in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my opinion, but; just like the case classes do, I would implement a `copy` method of sorts on the class to make the modification possible while keeping the immutability, but there exists some cases that I can't help to have it mutable; for example, when something  is expected to make the copy operation too large and slow for the class; like when the class has so many frequently-modified members. And don't worry about thousands of instances floating around in memory, because they are automatically GC'ed, so the more actual problem is the time cost of copying the class's instances. Please tell me if my opinion is somehow wrong :)

Comment: This makes sense to me. Do you know how I can perform a shallow copy of an immutable collection?

Comment: Just make another variable refer to the same object. If you want to shallow copy a variable `a` to `b`, then write `val b = a`. If you meant deep copy, it's pointless but perform something like `val b = Seq.empty ++ a` if it's `Seq`. :)